# How to import SHP file into docker PostgreSQL container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, openstreetmap, postgis, psql

Hallow Experts,

i am trying to import into PostgreSQL container "post_pl.shp" file.

I have succeeded to import osm file with this command:

```
osm2pgsql -H 172.17.0.2  -U postgres -d gis --hstore -s -S ./osm_stylesheet ./hessen-latest.osm.pbf
```

Now i need to do the same with post_pl.shp.

Tnx

Andrey

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it:

## to upload shp file do this:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 -W "latin1" post_pl.shp post_pl  > post_pl.sql

psql -h 172.17.0.2  U postgres -d gis -f post_pl.sql
```